# GWT code stuck on reactToMessages

Tags: java, gwt

While executing a GWT UI, execution is getting stuck in an infinite loop inside 
below code:

```
public void reactToMessages(SessionHandlerServer handler) {
    do {
      try {
        getStreamToOtherSide().flush();
        MessageType messageType = 
        Message.readMessageType(getStreamFromOtherSide());
    switch (messageType) {
      case FREE_VALUE:
        final FreeMessage freeMsg = FreeMessage.receive(this);
        handler.freeValue(this, freeMsg.getIds());
        break;
      case INVOKE:
        InvokeOnServerMessage imsg = InvokeOnServerMessage.receive(this);
        ExceptionOrReturnValue result = handler.invoke(this, imsg.getThis(),
            imsg.getMethodDispatchId(), imsg.getArgs());
        sendFreedValues();
        ReturnMessage.send(this, result);
        break;
      case INVOKE_SPECIAL:
        handleInvokeSpecial(handler);
        break;
      case QUIT:
        return;
      default:
        throw new RemoteDeathError(new BrowserChannelException(
            "Invalid message type " + messageType));
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RemoteDeathError(e);
  } catch (BrowserChannelException e) {
    throw new RemoteDeathError(e);
  }
} while (true);
```

}

I am working on GWT 2.7.0 but I have already tried changing to older versions, but alas, no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That loop is part of legacy "Dev Mode" (as replaced by "Super Dev Mode"): a plugin in your browser can connect to this JVM and communicate through by passing messages into this loop. Flow control is managed by throwing an exception, indicating that the browser has disconnected.

This loop is not a problem - each pass through the loop means that the browser has successfully called into the JVM to run part of your GWT app in Java, and then the Java returned control to the browser, so it should wait for the next call from JS into Java. In short, nothing is stuck if you are seeing this code execute, only the Dev Mode server is waiting for something to do.

In any production GWT, compiled to JS, this will simply not exist - control stays in the browser, since all Java is compiled into JS, so there is no need for any browser plugin management.

This plugin is not supported in recent Firefox or Chrome, Super Dev Mode should be used instead.